# jquery selector in success ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector

I am using an ajax function to paste data to a php script. On success I query a database and echo all itens like this:

```
include ("Database/RepairsdbConn.php");
$qryItem = $conn->prepare("SELECT SAP, Name FROM tblusedmaterial WHERE item = ?");
$Key = $_POST[MaterialTypeID];
$qryItem->execute(array($Key));
while($item = $qryItem->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" value="'.$item['SAP'].'" class="form-control input-sm">    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" value="'.$item['Name'].'" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 300px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 40px">    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="AddQuantity">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <p></p>';
}
```

This will create a form with all the products from the database and with an input to add the quantity and a button to click (+) to increase the quantity.

When I refer to the button on jquery nothing happens.

```
        $('#AddQuantity').click(function () {
            alert('TEST');
        });
```

How can I refer to each button only one time?

Comment: Do you defined AddQuantity click event handler before or after ajax call?

Comment: ID means identifier, and **has to be unique**. You can't have all your buttons with an ID of `AddQuantity`. Use a class.

Comment: No, id must be unique only in form!

Comment: But can I use jquery parent or child or nearest?

Comment: @Alexander What??? IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: The event is define after the ajax call

Comment: @A. Wolff, try to add two elements with the same id. What's happend?

Comment: @Alexander ya try it, what's happend when you want to bind event?... http://jsfiddle.net/7RYb9/

Comment: @Alexander The spec dictates that the ID has to be unique throughout the whole document. Browsers don't enforce that requirement when parsing HTML, but things like `document.getElementById()` will only return a single element with the specified ID, even if there are multiple. The whole point of an ID, and an ID selector, is to point to a single unique element.

Comment: The button as already a class from Bootstrap. Do I have to change this=

Comment: @A. Wolff, Anthony Grist, yes you are right. ID can be non unique, but it can add some troubles.

Comment: @user3163404 Just add a new class to it when generating the HTML in your PHP code. Unless Bootstrap is totally overwriting those it's not going to be a problem.

Comment: How can I add a new class? Do I have to delete the one on the button

Answer (score 0):

remove the id from the button and select the button with a class

```
    $('.col-md-4 .btn').on('click', function () {
        alert('TEST');
    });
```